# Cxf client JUnit: java.lang.ClassCastException: class MyService$MockitoMock$9v45s0v6 cannot be cast to class javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have simple cxf client and trying to write simple unit test. For now I am not intereseted in integration test thats why I mock my service.

In service implementation I need to get its current url:

```
(String) ((BindingProvider) myService).getRequestContext().get(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY)
```

And this line causes classcast: :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> xxx.MyService$MockitoMock$9v45s0v6 cannot be cast to class
> javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider (xxx.MyService$MockitoMock$9v45s0v6)

Because in unit test I am using:

```
@Mock
    private MyService myService ;
```

And MyService class is CXF generated client. How to create a simplest mock of it that would also be a BindingProvicer instance? In runtime everything works fine, when application is deployed, myService is always BindingProvider instance - the CXF library creates it but I don't know how.